# Dropdown list (combobox) disappears when saving PowerPoint 2010 document

Tags: vba, drop-down-menu, powerpoint, office-2010

I created a drop down list in Power Point 2010, which works very well before saving the document. I used the following code in VBA:

```
Sub AddItemsToSelectedListBox()

Dim oShape As Shape

Set oShape = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)

With oShape.OLEFormat.Object

' Add items to the list

.AddItem ("Good")

.AddItem ("Better")

.AddItem ("Best")

' You could work with other properties of the list or combo box here as well

End With

End Sub
```

f5 + close.

By going to the view modus, the drop down list works well. But if I save my power point document (in a .pptm format) and reopen the presentation, the lists don't drop down any more. If I enter the VBA, the code looks like this:

```
Sub AddItemsToSelectedListBox()

Dim oShape As Shape

Set oShape = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)

With oShape.OLEFormat.Object

' Add items to the list

.AddItem ("Good")

.AddItem ("Better")

.AddItem ("Best")

' You could work with other properties of the list or combo box here as well

End With

End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

End Sub
```

The ComboBox_Change() Part is new. (Why?)
Does anyone know, how to generate a dropdown list that survives the saving-process?
Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The _Change subroutine would be added when you doubleclick the combo box to get into the VBE.

If you load the combo box from a subroutine in a module, it doesn't seem to retain the values when you save and reopen.

If you load the combo box from an event in the box itself, it seems to work as you'd expect.

For example:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_GotFocus()

Dim oShape As Shape

Set oShape = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("ComboBox1")

With oShape.OLEFormat.Object
.Clear

' Add items to the list

.AddItem ("Good")

.AddItem ("Better")

.AddItem ("Best")

' You could work with other properties of the list or combo box here as well

End With
End Sub
```

Comment: But If I add more comboboxes (combobox1; combobox3; combobox5), only the last combobox is being saved and works if the presentation is reopened. The others are gone :-(

Comment: Are the others gone or are they there but empty?

Comment: the others are empty.
Entering the code, I see that in CB2 is the code of CB1 + Private Sub ComboBox2_Change()

End Sub. And so in CB3. It only saves the first ComboBox Code!?

Comment: Why not edit your original post to show the new code you're using ... that might help understand the problem.